# Bidirectional Binding Integer Table Field to ComboBox ItemIndex in RadStudio

Tags: delphi, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a INTEGER table field to the ITEMINDEX of a combobox.

The combobox have your items predefined at design time.

If I bind the SelectedValue with the Table field, the String related to the item, not your index, are passed, resulting in "not a integer value" exeception.

If I bind to the ItemIndex value, the link is UNIDIRECTIONAL, and I want a bidirectional bind.

There are a way of doing such binding?

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand your problem but i can give ideas as i understand.Pls picture it nexttime. First,if you want to add FruitDB.datas to combobox use formattext or
//select x from fruit order by fruitid asc
cb>style= dropdownlist and CB>add(Trim(fruitname)+space(5)+inttostr(Fruitid));
(apple   1
 pear    11
 apricot 12)
create 2 function return string and integer
seek for first space to i integer i=posstr(' ',cmb.item[x]) and
fruitname = copy(cmb.item[x],i,0) and fruitid= copy(reversestr(cmb.item[x]),Length(cmb.item[x])-(length(fruitname)+5),0)

and create 1 function again for indexof items return  integer like
seekincmb(fruitnm:string):integer
for id= 0 to iemcount -1do if fruitname(cmb.item[id]) = fruitnm then  result:= id break;or if you need fruitid ,you can add it too.
you call them in cmbOnchange or OndrawItem or where you want.
if you wont search on combo,use cmb.drawitem and fruitname function for display item
if you want search on combo,put an editbox on combobox and fix edge, editonchange or keypress or keyup,seek cmb.itemindex:= seekincmb( edittext);

Comment: Please learn how to use the SO editor.  To enter a block of code, copy it to the paste buffer and then into the editor and then press Ctrl-K.  Or, enter 4 spaces before each line of code.

Comment: Btw, it is pointless to post an answer when you yourself say "I do not understand your problem."

Comment: because my language isnt english but this will help your problem a bit?